# htaccess RewriteCond: Why doesn't a server variable match itself?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting, bootstrapping

Perhaps a better question would be, is there any way to use server variables in the matching string?

For example, I can't understand why this fails to match:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} %{REQUEST_URI}
```

First, two points.

1. I know this condition servers no purpose as is.
2. I know I have poor knowledge of both htaccess and regex.

What I want is to generically turn this URL **www.example.com/dir/path/info** into **www.example.com/dir?foo=/path/info** for bootstrapping.

I tried to accomplish this by removing the extra path info from the deepest actual directory in the URL. I was trying this code to test the premise:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Multiviews -Indexes +FollowSymLinks   
RewriteBase /
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)%{PATH_INFO}
RewriteRule ^(.+?) index.php?dir=%1&path=%2 [L]
```

No luck. To troubleshoot I reduced it to this:

```
RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} (.+)
RewriteRule ^(.+?) index.php?dir=%1 [L]
```

As expected the query returned foo='/path/info'

So I tried this which I thought would match no matter what:
    RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} %{PATH_INFO}

That failed so as a last attempt, I tried capturing the string:

```
RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} (.+)
RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} %1
```

That also failed to find a match which has me baffled. %1 should be the complete %{PATH_INFO} string. How could it not match itself???

I don't think it matters but I'm using XAMPP on Windows7 in FastCGI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite *pattern* params only allow regex (tho Condpattern also has special flags for tests and comparisons):

RewriteCond TestString ***CondPattern***
RewriteRule ***Pattern*** Substitution

Server variables like %{REQUEST_URI} can only be used in Teststring and Substitution. The following docs outline this usage:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

If this will go in your main .htaccess, perhaps try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ index.php?dir=/$1&path=/$2 [L]
```

**Two more Example**:

Sample1

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?index.php(/.+) index.php?dir=/$1&path=$2 [R,L]
```

Sample2

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^((.+/)?index.php)(/.+) $1?path=$3 [R,L]
```

Sample3

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?(.+\.php)(/.+) $1$2?foo=$3 [R,L]
```

these all do external rewrite so you can see result in the browser address. To revert to internal rewrite, just remove [R] flag

Comment: Thank you. That is a comprehensive answer as to why they don't match. But I'm still surprised that I couldn't capture the string with RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} (.+)  and then pass the string with a backreference %1. So it seems that there is absolutely no way for ,htaccess to locate the deepest existing directory automatically. I find that so strange because %{REQUEST_FILENAME} does just that. Luckily I don't have enough hair left to pull out.

Comment: @GregorMacgregor Intended use of PATH_INFO is to match everything after script name and before querystring. However, I don't see way to extract the script directory (if that's what you trying to do?) by parsing out PATH_INFO. Still do not have clear picture of final goal, but I added two more examples to answer above.

Comment: Evidently I was going at it backwards. What I wanted was a way to break the request in half at the script name. Imagine this. www.example.com/dir/file.php/some/option . This is a bad URL which returns 404. I wanted to catch the file and rewrite the URL to  www.example.com/dir/file.php?foo=/some/option . In this way I could use a normal bootstrap to my main index.php but also add special files and folders without altering htaccess for each and every situation.

Comment: What I want to is a tiny, tight htaccess file that flows smoothly though alternate situations. Rather than a file that grows more cumbersome and convoluted every time I make a change to my folder structure or add a new type of file.

Comment: @GregorMacgregor My experience is more with just standard Apache distrib, Rewrite URL manipulation and regex. Not so good with php integration :( But for the requirement you state in last update, the best template i can think would just be to keep "php" in pattern if this will be reliable constant and allow everything else to be flexible for same style of redirection. Updated answer with Sample 3.

Comment: I found a solution which I've post below. As you said, you can not compare two variables directly because variables can not be used in the condition pattern. But what you CAN do is put both variables in the test string and look for a duplication with regex. 'code' RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}%{REQUEST_URI} (\/.+)\1+ 'code' this will give you the part of the file name which is also in the URL. And therefore you have extracted a url to the actual file.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found a way to accomplish this goal.

Basically I was trying to compare two server variables. htaccess won't do that. I wanted to extract part of a "pretty" url which points to an actual file or folder. The variable ${SCRIPT_URL} should do that, but it is either depreciated or not reliable. The work around is to put both variables in the test string and use a regex back reference to find the point of duplication.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}%{PATH_INFO} (.*?)(/.+)\2$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1.php?strappath=%2 [QSA,END]
```

In the above example %1 will be the uri of the file and %2 will be the remaining path after the URI, duplicating %{PATH_INFO}.

Follow with this rule for when there is no extra path info

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)$ $1.php [QSA,END]
```

If no .php file is found, I want the index of that directory and add the un-found file name to the pathinfo. This is a bit trickier.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)(/.+)$
RewriteCond %1 -d
RewriteCond %1/index.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}%{PATH_INFO} ^(.*?)(/.+)\2$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/.+)(/.+)?$
RewriteCond %1 ^(.*)(/.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/index.php?strappath=%2%{PATH_INFO} [QSA,END]
```

The above section fails to catch urls that point directly to an existing folder with an index.php, so to catch those:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php -f
RewriteCond ^(.+)$ $1/index.php [QSA,END]
```

I doubt anyone ever finds this useful but I've seen variations of this question asked over and over with no working solution given.